# Array and structures initialization

Tags: c, initialization, structure, c99

Firstly, I'll put this in the short form: How can I initialize the structure and vector below with the desired values (0xFF and 0x41)?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char var1[5];
    unsigned int  var2[7]; 
} ST_struct;

int main()
{
    ST_struct myStruct = {0xFF};
    
    unsigned char *pChar = (unsigned char *)&myStruct;
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(ST_struct); i++)
    {
        printf("Struct - %d\n", pChar[i]); // This will print {0xff, 0, 0, 0...}
    }
    
    unsigned char myChar[20] = {0x41};
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(myChar); i++)
    {
        printf("Char - %d\n", myChar[i]); // This will print {0x41, 0, 0, 0 ...}
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the 'long' explanation:
I have local and static variables of different types that must have an initial value different from zero. However, for the fact it must store information, I can not use some memset to initialize it after it's declaration. So, how can I ensure its initial values?

And this method should be in accordance with C99 standard.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

- Initialize every byte/field with `= {xff, xff, xff...}` is not an option. Once, some structs/arrays could be lengthy (KB).
- Using a flag to signalize the initialization is not feasible. For, it's an embedded code and there'll be a huge amount of this procedure.
- It should be compiler independent.

Comment: How is the behavior of the code you present different from what you want?

Comment: 0xFF cannot be the value of the struct. It can be the value of each field of the struct, separately. If this is the case, you need to initialise each field, separately. `ST_struct myStruct = {0xFF};` only initialises the first field, which is `myStruct.var1[0]`, to 0xFF. The rest is filled with zeros. `ST_struct myStruct = {0xFF, 0xFF};` initialises the first two fields,  `myStruct.var1[0]` and `myStruct.var1[1]`. And so on.

Comment: gcc and clang have an extension to designated initializers known as an array range, which looks like `char myChar[20] = { [0 ... 19] = 0x41 };` If you need strict C99 compliance, then you'll have to type `0x41, ` twenty times.

Comment: The other solution is a flag variable `static int first_call = true;` Do any one-time initialization when `first_call` is true, and then set it to false.

Comment: Could you use a union between an `int` and the structure? Then you can initialize the `int` part to the desired hex value.